# python plotly: how to stretch line chart out to the end

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have two subplots of line chart, and I'd like the line to start from the very beginning and stretch it all the way to the end. It seems like if I were to draw an area chart, it stretches it out automatically, but when I try it with a line chart, it does not stretch to the end.

The line charts don't stretch from the beginning to the end as shown below:

[image: line_chart]

Whereas, if I were to draw an area chart by inserting `stackgroup = "one"`, it automatically starts from the very beginning and stretches out to the end:

[image: area_chart]

Here is the reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots 

rng = pd.date_range('2022-04-09', periods=20, freq='D')
np.random.seed(42)
first_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))}) 
first_df['Type'] = 'A'

second_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))}) 
second_df['Type'] = 'B'

final_df =  pd.concat([first_df,second_df]).sort_values(by = 'Date')
final_df['Is_Weekend'] = np.where((final_df['Date'].dt.weekday == 5), 1, 0 )

A_df = final_df[final_df['Type']=='A']
B_df = final_df[final_df['Type']=='B']

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes=True)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=A_df['Date'], 
                         y = A_df['Val'], 
                         line_color = 'orange',
                         mode = 'lines+markers',
                         showlegend = True, name = "A"),
              row=1, col=1,
              secondary_y = False)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=B_df['Date'], 
                         y = B_df['Val'], 
                         line_color = 'blue',
                         mode = 'lines+markers',
                         showlegend = True, name = "B"),
              row=2, col=1,
              secondary_y = False)


fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder="reversed", hovermode = "x unified", yaxis_tickformat = ".1%")

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder="reversed", hovermode = "x unified", yaxis_tickformat = ".1%")
```

into:

```
fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder="reversed", hovermode = "x unified", yaxis_tickformat = ".1%",
                  xaxis_range=[A_df['Date'][0],A_df['Date'][len(A_df)-1]])
```

Result:

[image: updated plot]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Do you happen to know how to order legends (A then B)? I already have `fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder="reversed"` which does not order the legends as I want them to be.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please close the question by accepting it. As to your follow-up question: you want to use `legend_traceorder="normal"` rather than `reversed`. In this way "the items are displayed top-to-bottom in the same order as the input data" (see [traceorder](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-legend-traceorder)). So: A, then B.

Comment: Needed to add .iloc[] to capture index: `xaxis_range=[A_df['Date'].iloc[0],A_df['Date'].iloc[len(A_df)-1]]`